# Presentation techniques for YouTube

Tags: youtube, technical

I watched some videos on YouTube and for not being professional in the area, I would like to know how I could denominate the track that shows the name of the presenter?

Is there a technical name for this kind of presentation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Russian we have term for them — плашка.

English name I personally don't like — [Lower third](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_third)

I was making them in After Effects. With animations, dynamic text, etc. There is a lot of tutorial ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNLcSh8Diow)), how you can make one. 
But I believe that without animations you can make them in a lot of other video editing apps. It is basically a type of Title (Premiere Pro). Or art with alpha channel in any software, which allow to compose picture on top of the video.

You can achieve similar result directly on YouTube with annotations. Similar to [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/22405/11523). It will not look so good, but can contain text information.

Comment: I actually use PowerPoint a lot of times in live webcast production

Comment: @pojo-guy, How do you add PowerPoint presentation in video? Or you export slides as pictures?

Comment: We do live webcast. The output of the poweroint is fed to the inputs of the ATEM switch. We use either chroma keying (green screen) or luma keying (graphic channel + alpha channel) depending on the graphic we are presenting. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1as_O1hjGQ at 8:34.  You will see a left-quarter luma-keyed panel, The only difference is the graphic for a bottom third.  If I have to do titles in post production I use Premiere Pro